# Правило .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите написать правило для `.htaccess`, чтобы после `.php` запретить ввод `/`. И если человек его вводит, то ему выдавалась бы ошибка 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается следующим образом:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.php/$ [L,NC,R=404]
```

Это правило обработает все адреса вида `что-то-там.php/`. Если же надо запретить и добавление произвольного текста после `.php/`, то правило нужно записать по-другому:

```
RewriteRule \.php/ [L,NC,R=404]
```

В этом случае будут обработаны также и адреса вида `что-то-там.php/что-то-ещё`.

Comment: наверное $ лишний, сейчас rgjgld.php/fgdf не попадет

Comment: @splash58 А должен? Просили только запрет  `.php/`.

Comment: По каким то причинам, у меня на сайте, человек может зайти на index.php/fasfda/ и ему выдаст 200 ок, и страницу index.php

Comment: ну, уберите там $, и будет вам счастье

Comment: @Егор Обновил ответ.

Comment: В общем, у меня не работает привожу пример всего htaccess RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.php/$ [L,NC,R=404]
RewriteRule \.php/ [L,NC,R=404]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: в общем посмотрите сами bpto-brozex.ru

Comment: @Егор Работает как надо. `http://bpto-brozex.ru/price.php/` - "Извините, но мы не смогли найти эту страницу…" Кэш у браузера почистите.

Comment: Спасибо)))Очень помогли